# Multiple Condition to Insert with Multiple query in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I need to insert data into 3 table Like `table-01`, `table-02`, `table-03` in 3 difference condition. if `condition 1 = true` then insert into `table-01`, if `condition 1 = true` then insert into `table-01`, if `condition 1 = true` then insert into `table-01` & if all 3 condition is true then insert in all 3 table.

`condition-01`, `condition-02`, `condition-03` from 3 input value

```
var1 > 0
var2 > 0
var3 > 0
var4 > 0
```

My Try:

```
if(var1 > 0){
    $res = "INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2, col3) VALUES ('1', '2', '3')";
}
if(var2 > 0){
    $res = "INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2, col3) VALUES ('1', '2', '3')";
}
if(var3 > 0){
    $res = "INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2, col3) VALUES ('1', '2', '3')";
}
```

Need help for insert in right way...

Comment: should be `$var1` and so on

Comment: What you have done to achieved the tasks show us..

Comment: sorry my mistake in my try:     if($var1 > 0){
    $res = "INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2, col3) VALUES ('1', '2', '3')";
}
if($var2 > 0){
    $res = "INSERT INTO table2 (col1, col2, col3) VALUES ('1', '2', '3')";
}
if($var3 > 0){
    $res = "INSERT INTO table3 (col1, col2, col3) VALUES ('1', '2', '3')";
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition you are applying should be descending as for example

```
$x = 5; // let say 

if($x > 1){
     // your code runs in this block 
}
if($x > 2){
    // this condition is also true   
}
// also you have not used else if so multiple conditions will be true
```

So for your condition you should use

```
if($x > 3  && $x > 2 && $x > 1){
      // condition if all condition are true
}else if($x>3){
    // condition 1 
}else if($x > 2){
    // condition 2
} // so on .....
```